# How to do this JS script in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

How can get this example in nodejs I've tried to use this https://github.com/node-file-api/file-api but not works very well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File API</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    <output id="list"></output>

    <script>
      function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
          output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                      f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                      f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>');
        }
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
      }

      document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to build a nodejs api to upload a file? Learn Nodejs and create nodejs apis.

Comment: Please describe in words what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Bhuneshwer I'm filtering files with specific date of motification to send via email. I don't know how can I get the file properties with de motification date.